# Error: Could not resolve the package 'app' in 'package:app/app_controller.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

In my last flutter project, I included files placed in my `lib/` directory by using `import 'package:app/file_name.dart'`.

For example, my file located at `lib/app_controller.dart` was imported via:

```
import 'package:app/app_controller.dart'
```

I just started a new flutter project, and it is giving me the error:

```
Error: Could not resolve the package 'app' in 'package:app/app_controller.dart'
```

When I remove the portion `package:app/`, it builds fine. I find this very strange because my previous project is still building just fine without any changes. Does anyone know what's happening here?

What is allowing my old project to respect `package:app/...`, but not my new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`package:app/` would work only for an application that is called **app**. What is the name of your new application? When you import items from your own project, it goes like this:

`package:{{YOUR APPLICATION NAME}}/{{DIRECTORIES}}`

What is the name in your `pubspec.yaml` file? It's usually on the very first line.

Answer (score 1):

it is because a dart class can be imported in two ways(AFAIK),

1. local import from the root of current file where import is being used for example `import '../folder/file.dart`
2. with a package name which should begin from package for example `import package:packagename/any_file_in_the_lib_folder.dart`, a package will have a pubspec.yml which defines a package name which will be used to import the content of the lib folder of that package, in your case your first project is named app so it respected this import style but your second project isn't respecting it because its not named app but something else.